# Ruby - replace characters in a string with a symbol

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to receive a string of characters and change all characters aside from spaces to "*". Here is where I am:

```
def change_word(word)
  new_word.each {|replace| replace.gsub!(/./, "*") }
  new_word.to_s
  new_word.join
end
```

I'm taking a word, adding the individual characters to an array and assigning this to a new variable, replacing everything in said array with the required symbol, changing everything in the array to a string and then joining everything in the array to output a bunch of *'s.

What I would like to do (and it's not necessary that the solution follows the previous syntax) is take all letters and replace them with *. Spaces should stay as a space, only letters should become *.

Comment: Suppose `str = "Hey, diddle-didle,\nthe cat and the fiddle."`. Replacing all characters other than spaces with an asterisk produces `str.gsub(/[^ ]/,'*')
# => "**** ***************** *** *** *** *******"`. Replacing all characters other than whitespace with an asterisk produces `str.gsub(/\S/,'*')
 #=> "**** *************\n*** *** *** *** *******"`, Those are not the same because `"\n"` is a whitespace character. Since you awarded the green to @mrasa I assume you want the latter, but it's not what you asked for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about `gsub(/\S/, '*')`

It will find all non-whitespace characters and  replace every one of them with `*`. `\S` is a [regex character class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes) matching non-whitespace chars (thanks @jdno).

E.g.

```
 pry> "as12 43-".gsub(/\S/, '*')
 => "**** ***"
```

So in your case:

```
def change_word(word)
   word.gsub(/\S/, '*')
end
```

You may also extract the regex outside of the method to optimize it a bit:

```
CHANGE_WORD_PATTERN = /\S/
def change_word(word)
   word.gsub(CHANGE_WORD_PATTERN, '*')
end
```

Comment: It is worth noting that `\S` is a character class, and that it matches any non-whitespace character. A list of all character classes can be found in the documentation of the `Regex` module: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes

Answer (score 0):

When the first argument from the `tr` method of String starts with "^", then it means: everything but. So "^ " means everything but a space.

```
word = "12 34 rfv"
word.tr("^ ","*")  # => "** ** ***"
```